# What kind of signing do I need to use IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_FORCE_INTEGRITY?

Tags: windows, code-signing, code-signing-certificate, authenticode, windows-security

One of my toy projects require IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_FORCE_INTEGRITY in PE header to run. I've been testing it with test signing on, but I'm considering buying a cert if I can afford.

The documents on this are too old, so I'm not sure whether the application would be signed with a cross-signing cert which is used for kernel-mode signing or an Authenticode code signing cert. Though the latter is much cheaper, making a try is still not affordable to me.

[This article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/255.forced-integrity-signing-of-portable-executable-pe-files.aspx) only talks about signing procudures, but not cert requirements. [This one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/integritycheck-require-signature-check?view=msvc-170) suggests using the *Microsoft Azure Code Signing* project, while not explaining details. Raxi on Stack Overflow, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66424613/windows-firewall-looking-for-user-interaction-api), claims that Authenticode signing would be enough, but I cannot find this from references.

So is Authenticode signing enough to have an executable with IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_FORCE_INTEGRITY run?

Thanks to anyone knowing about this and kind enough to help.

Comment: [Forced Integrity Signing of Portable Executable (PE) files](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/255.forced-integrity-signing-of-portable-executable-pe-files.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As the Microsoft's own [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/integritycheck-require-signature-check?view=msvc-170#signing-integritycheck-files) says:

> Microsoft has new signing guidance for DLL and executable files linked by using `/INTEGRITYCHECK`. The guidance used to recommend a cross-signed certificate from the cross-signing program. However, the [cross-signing program is now deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/deprecation-of-software-publisher-certificates-and-commercial-release-certificates). You must now sign your `/INTEGRITYCHECK` files by using the Microsoft [Azure Code Signing](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/security-compliance-and-identity/azure-code-signing-democratizing-trust-for-developers-and/ba-p/3604669) program instead.

Answer (score -1):

I have an Authenticode certificate, and can confirm that it's not enough to be able to successfully load PE files with that flag. I would theorically be able to if there was a cross signing chain for the root CA of my Authenticode cert, but only driver signing certificates have a root CA that Microsoft cross signs.

You would need a kernel mode driver certificate (even if you are not actually making drivers) to sign the executable with.

Supposedly, once Azure Code Signing becomes publically available (in whoever knows how long), you would be able to (at no charge) sign files in such a manner that this flag will work.

Comment: I tried signing with an EV code-signing certificate an exe that was built with the `/integritycheck` linker command line option and it still resulted in the same warning. My guess is that the executable has to be signed by Microsoft (like a kernel driver, for instance.)

Answer (score -1):

You can use an OLD out of date kernel signing certificate with cross signing, if you have one....
(will require to move backward your pc clock)
no time stamp needed, and ussually the os doesnt checks that the certificate is obsolete... (not for kernel drivers at least)